# how to pass value to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having following data ,I need to pass it to array

```
 coulmns = [
        { field: 'A', caption: 'Date/Time', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'B', caption: 'Measured', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'C', caption: 'Systolic/Diastolic', size: '40%' }
            //          { field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date', size: '120px' }
    ];
            records = [
    { "recid": 1, "A": "01/02/2014 ", "B": "Siting", "C": "141/78" },
    { "recid": 2, "A": "01/02/2014 ", "B": "Siting", "C": "141/78" },
    { "recid": 3, "A": "01/02/2014 ", "B": "Siting", "C": "141/78" },
    { "recid": 4, "A": "01/02/2014 ", "B": "Siting", "C": "141/78" }
    ]
```

actually I have 3 columns  named
1) Date/time
2)Measured
3)Systolic/dystolic

and  there is data for each column,
now I want to make an array so that I can bind the data for respective column, firstly I need to do it with hard coded value,please suggest me how can I acive this,the code I have posted in json format,it is just for data reference

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what your question exactly is: Do you need a hint how to build an object/array or how to access data provided by the JSON you posted? Or both?

Comment: actually I want to bind hardcoded data to array in the format I specifies like all the date related data will come under date column and measured related data come under measured column and so on...the data I have posted is nothing to do it with ..it is for refrence of data

Comment: Okay, but again: What is your specific problem? What do you mean with "bind". Do you want to build up another array/object structure? How it is going to be processed? What should the result actually look like? The "reference of data' JSON is already quite usable for a number of things...